# Determining null sets with Tonelli's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How can I show that the diagonal $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\vert  x=y\}$ is a Lebesgue-nullset in $\mathbb R^2$ by utilizing the theorem of Tonelli?

My solution so far, but it doesn't seem quite right:

$\int_D 1d\lambda = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{y}^{y}1dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty [x]^y_ydy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty0 dy=0$

Can I do it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sigma, Your approach is essentially correct. You can prove the diagonal $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\vert  x=y\}$ is a nullset **directly** from Tonelli's theorem. Here are the details.

Since $D$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$, $D$ is measurable and so $1_D$ is a non-negative measurable function. So we can apply Tonelli's theorem.

\begin{align*} \lambda(D)&=\int_{\mathbb R^2} 1_D d\lambda = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}1_D(x,y) dx dy= \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}1_D(x,y) dx\right) dy = \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}1_{\{y\}} dx\right) dy = \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 0\; dy =0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach: first rotate $D$ to the horizontal axis, and recall that the Lebesgue measure is invariant under rotations. Then observe that
$$
(-\infty,+\infty) \times \{0\} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left( [-n,n] \times \{0\} \right).
$$
If you prove that $\mathcal{L}^1 \left( [-n,n] \times \{0\} \right)=0$ for every $n$, then you can use the subadditivity of the measure to conclude.

We must show that $\mathcal{L}^1 \left( [-n,n] \times \{0\} \right)=0$ for every $n$. Pick $\varepsilon >0$ and consider the set
$$
\Omega_\varepsilon = [-n,n] \times (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon).
$$
Compute $\int_{\Omega_\varepsilon} \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y$ and prove that the result is of order $\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary...

**Edit:** the first step is only for convenience. One can also consider the set $\Omega_\varepsilon$ lying between the lines $y=x+\varepsilon$ and $y=x-\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. But to be honest, we haven't shown that the Lebesgue measure is invariant under rotations yet (we know it is true, but we are not allowed to utilize it).

Comment: This is not essential, you can "cover" $D$ by a slab with sides parallel to the line $y=x$.